# Как python считает стандартную функцию stdev из statistics?

Tags: python, статистика

В python есть функция стандартного отклонения из библиотеки statistics. Есть несколько похожих функций на данной странице по ним есть небольшой мануал https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html#statistics.variance

Никак не могу понять, как узнать какая формула лежит в основе stdev? Считается ли она как стандартное отклонение для генеральной совокупности или как стандартное отклонение для выборки? Просто идет расхождение с другими источниками и все не могу понять какая функция вшита в стандартную библиотеку статистики для python.

Comment: Вы можете пометить ответ, как правильный, если он вам помог. Рекомендую вам обратить внимание в этом плане и на предыдущие свои вопросы. Таким образом вы сообщаете сообществу, что ваша проблема решена, а также что решение, приведённое в ответе, работает в вашем случае.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функции стандартной библиотеки обычно имеют достаточно хорошую документацию. Получить доступ к ней можно с помощью функции `help`

```
import statistics
help(statistics.variance)
```

Там указано, что эта функция отвечает за стандартное отклонение для выборки, для генеральной совокупности же следует использовать функцию `pvariance`.

Более того, обычно в документации указывается ссылка на исходный код модуля, и при необходимости вы можете посмотреть на [реализацию этого метода](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/statistics.py#l471).